# React: Use component inside another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I'm new to react so I hope the questions isn't too stupid.

In short: I want to use a certain Component inside another components props.
But it isn't working like desired.

I want to use [Material UI Cards](https://material-ui.com/demos/cards/) in following Component:
[Link to repo of "Material-UI Tree View"](https://github.com/helfi92/material-ui-treeview#readme)

For testing I wrote following code:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import SplitPane from "react-split-pane";
import MuiTreeView from 'material-ui-treeview';
import Demo from './demo';


export class App extends Component {
    render() {

        const tree = [
            {
                value: 'Parent A',
                nodes: [{ value: Demo}]
            }

        ];
        return (
            <SplitPane split="vertical"  defaultSize={500} allowResize={false}>

                <div><MuiTreeView tree={tree} /></div>
                <div id="mynetwork"></div>
            </SplitPane>
        );
    }
}
```

The import

```
import Demo from './demo';
```

is the example Simple Card: https://codesandbox.io/s/3vl744v6z5

In my index.js I render the App Component like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I hope that you could give me a tip where to have a look at.

Thanks in advance,

coloeus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MuiTreeView` expects a tree with on each leaf node a `.value` member which is the *string* to be rendered. It simply does not support injecting custom components in this way.

You can tell by looking at its [`prop-types`](https://github.com/helfi92/material-ui-treeview/blob/0a38ef687933c314bdd7a2fdd8ff52b66507ba68/src/components/MuiTreeView/index.jsx#L63)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I will remember to look in the prop-types in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No can do, as in checking in the source files of MuiTreeView, [tree prop](https://github.com/helfi92/material-ui-treeview/blob/0a38ef687933c314bdd7a2fdd8ff52b66507ba68/src/components/MuiTreeView/index.jsx#L63) can only be either a string, or recursively an object where props values are strings...

Since you're using MaterialUI components, try checking the [expansion panels](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-accordion/) that MUI provides and try to get the desired results. In this case, no need to pass your components as props.

Comment: Thank you. The reason why I wanted to use MuiTreeView is that the MaterialUI Expansion panels don't support nesting. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9921